# Limit the returned subdocuments mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nested

So lets say I have a data set as follows

```
{
"username": "myUsername",
"2018": { //year
        "totalData": 1000
        01: { //month
            "totalData": 30
            01: { //day
                "totalData": 1
                01: { //hour
                    "totalData": 0
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 0
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 1
                }                   
                //etc

            }
            02: {
                "totalData": 12
                01: { //hour
                    "totalData": 3
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 6
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 3
                }                   
                //etc                   
            }
            03: {
                "totalData": 6
                01: { //hour
                    "totalData": 4
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 1
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 1
                }                   
                //etc                   
            }
                //...etc
            31: {
                "totalData": 1
                01: { //hour
                    "totalData": 0
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 0
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 1
                }                   
                //etc                   
            }
        }
        02: {
            "totalData": 51
            01: {
                "totalData": 17
                01: { //hour
                    "totalData": 5
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 5
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 7
                }                   
                //etc                   
            }
            02: {
                "totalData": 1
                01: { //hour
                    "totalData": 0
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 0
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 1
                }                   
                //etc                   
            }
            03: {
                "totalData": 7
                01: { //hour
                    "totalData": 6
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 0
                }
                02: {
                    "totalData": 1
                }                   
                //etc                   
            }
                //...etc
            30: {
                "totalData": 5
            }
        }       

    }
}
```

So I am tracking data usage by year, by month then by day, each with the total usage for that year/month/day

For now this is fine, however I will be going into hours & minutes at some point and I would not like to return the entire document when its not needed.

So I would like to do a query that somehow limits the "depth" of the query.

So I would to return one an initial query, for example, in 2018 how much data was used each month. then on the front end, how the user drill down as far as they need to go, but as this can get quite big, it seems a massive waste to pull this full document everytime.

So for example, is it possible to do a query to return only a limited response or depth of subdocuments

```
{
2018: {
        "totalData": 1000
        01: {
            "totalData": 30
        }
        02: {
            "totalData": 51
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use **projection** on embedded documents like the examples given in the official Mongo documentation :

- [Return Specific Fields in Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/index.html#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents)
- [Suppress Specific Fields in Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/index.html#suppress-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents)

For you case, you can try :

```
db.collection.find({},{"2018.totalData":1, "2018.01.totalData": 1, "2018.02.totalData":1 })
```

Comment: Thanks! but as you can imagine it would get very messy to try pull all months & days with a query like this. Is there way to do this more dynamically? i.e without a massively long query?